# What is Kubernetes Cluster in Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new in Docker. I am trying to understand the cluster in Kubernetes but getting a bit confused.

**Can anyone help me to understand the Kubernetes cluster in Docker with details?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes vs. Docker: What Does It Really Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345741/kubernetes-vs-docker-what-does-it-really-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is a container orchestration system integrated into docker installation on windows (that you might mean in the question).
When you install docker on windows 10, you can opt for running kubernetes or not.

In general, if you select the option of running k8s (kubernetes) - it will run a very small cluster of kubernetes that should be, nevertheless, good enough to fiddle with kubernetes commands.

You can perfectly run docker without kubernetes as well to start containers, play with them and build your own. but if you think about how to manage many containers in your environment, that check out the kubernetes. Again, my advice is to learn docker first.

As an extremely "high level" overview of what is kubernetes and what does it do for you once you've grasped the docker concepts, you can consider watching [This short movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ht22ReBjno)

Answer (score 1):

My response is based on the assumption that with so many videos and reading material online, you got overwhelmed and hence reached out to the community to get the information where to start from. I was in the same boat almost a year ago and could not figure out the starting point. With my experience, I am listing down publicly available resources which could be followed to gain information on the relation between the two -

1. Step 1: Start with [the difference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vMEQ5zs1ko) between the two
2. Step 2: After that move on to understand [the difference between two
   real key terms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmrAGliHvzQ)
3. Step 3: Establish a [basic understanding of k8s](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLot-YkcC7wZ9xwMzkzR_EkOrPahSofe5Q)
4. Step 4: Prepare [lab on the local machine](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)
5. Step 5: Dig deeper into [Kubernetes cluster setup](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)
6. Step 6: Putting [all the pieces together](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293725)
7. Step 7: All set to rock n roll